# Rotational spring

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I am looking to model a rotational spring, e.g. a balance wheel of a mechanical clock. The [rigid body constraint/generic spring] only allow for translational springs. 
How could I do this?

Comment: are you looking to simulate, or just model that spring?

Comment: I am looking to simulate this. Just any object would behave like a rotational oscillator.  To model the spiral spring geometry is the next step, but this should be easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using...

## Shape Keys + Curve Modifier + Skin Modifier

Enable the **Add Curves: Extra Objects** add-on.

[image: Enabling the Add Curve: Extra Objects add-on]

**Add > Curve > Spiral**

Adjust the spiral as you like. I recommend a high step count for a nice looking SubSurf.

[image: Add Spring - Operator Panel settings]

Convert to Mesh (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>)

**Add > Curve > Circle**

To your spiral object, add the following modifiers:

**Curve** - Set the object to be your BezierCircle

**Skin** - Smooth Shading

**SubSurf** - 3 Subdivision levels

[image: Rotational spring - modifier settings]

Create two Shape Keys - a Basis one where the spring is fully squished, and a second one where the spring is scaled up on Z, fully sprung... [ahem].

[image: Rotational spring - shape keys]

You can then animate the Shape Key slider to make the spring extend.

[image: Rotational spring extending]

[image]

Comment: Nice work, but a rotational spring doesn't work like that.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_wheel#/media/File:Pocket_Watch_Balance_Wheel.jpg

Comment: @Xtremity Ha! ...crap. Well thanks for pointing it out. I'll give this some thought and post again if I solve it. Not that OP even seems to be following anymore, but in case others come searching. This is why reference photos are a good thing.

Comment: Oh, I didnt know how I can add a reference foto. I thought the term 'rotational spring' and balance wheel for a mechanical clock is reference enough. The problems still stands though.

Answer (score 0):

I did this to model a roll of thick plastic - My way was to create a spiral in adobe illustrator , add a stroke to it, expand the stroke so it becomes one solid spiral shape and then exported it as an SVG file.

I then imported the SVG into blender and extruded it along a single axis.

Comment: This is not a good solution either since a spiral spring changes diameter while its rotated.